# OS X deletes all files and doesn't send them to the Trash first

Tags: osx-lion, trash

Recently I found that when I delete a file, it asks for my password and then it will delete the file permanently without going into the Trash first.

Any way to change that, so that I could retrieve the files in case if I delete something by mistake?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: iOS Lion 10.7.3

Comment: It happens to any files. I could not find any deleted files in the trash bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting and recreating your Trash. Open up a Terminal and enter:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash
```

If that doesn't work, try the same with sudo – make sure you copy and paste this command exactly as it is, otherwise you're deleting every single file you own. You have been warned:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash
```

Finally, recreate the Trash folder:

```
mkdir ~/.Trash
```

Now we only have to restart Finder. Enter:

```
killall Finder
```

If that doesn't work, post the output of `ls -laO ~/.Trash` in your question.

Comment: Done, it works after the sudo step, thanks alot man! Great help!